# Preselect the dropdown using knockout is not working

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

On page load i am getting drpDownValue as null.

I am able to update drpDownValue as 1 in computed function. But in UI dropdown is not selected by default.

I need to select the Enable option by default in dropdown. Please help me to fix this issue

```
 <select data-bind="options: Options, optionsCaption: ' ', optionsText: 'Value', optionsValue: 'Key', value: drpDownValue}"></select>

var EditModel = function () {
  var drpDownValue = ko.observable(0);
  var Options = ko.observableArray([{ Key: 1, Value: "Enable" }]);
  var Test= ko.computed(function() {
      drpDownValue(1);
  });

return {
  drpDownValue: drpDownValue,
  Options: Options,
  Test: Test
};
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're giving knockout a list with one item in, and telling it that it's value is `1`.  You're then setting the value of the select, via `drpDownValue` to a default of `0`.  Since that doesn't exist as a value in your list of items, nothing is selected.

If you want to use `1` as the default, just update your observable to default to that instead of `0`:

```
var drpDownValue = ko.observable(1);
```

Note that this doesn't really tally with the fact that you're *also* setting the `optionsCaption`, [which is meant for when you don't want to select one by default](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/options-binding.html#parameters) and instead want to display something like "Please choose" instead.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I want to update the value for  drpDownValue on page load. Value is getting updated but in UI its not getting reflected. ie dropdown not getting selected with Enable.